# Python - Match Words in Text File to Dictionary and Manipulate Value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary where the keys are simple words and the values are a score.  I want to calculate a score based upon the frequency of the word and the score (value) stored in the dictionary compared to mathed words in a file (or string).  For example, suppose my text was:

"Dogs are great pets and hamsters are bad pets. That is why I want a dog"

My dictionary is:

Dict = {'dogs' : 5, 'hampsters' : -2}

Then I would want to calculate a score of 8 ((2x5)-2 = 8).  I can find occurences in the dictionary with

```
    for key in Dict: 
    m = re.findall(key, READ , re.IGNORECASE)
```

but I haven't been able to access the value of the key in a useful manner.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: The word `dogs` only appears once in that string; the other word is `dog`. The fact that these two words are 'the same' in some sense is not known to the computer unless you use a pluralisation library.

Comment: Careful calling a variable `Dict` You are OK in this case, because of the capital 'D' but if you call your variable `dict` you have trashed the built-in dict constructor.

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Steve V inspired the following, which is rather nicer:

```
sentence = "...".split()
score = sum(sentence.count(word) * score for word, score in scores.items())
```

---

The obligatory one-liner:

```
>>> s = "Dogs are great pets and hamsters are bad pets. That is why I want a dog."
>>> scores = {'dogs': 5, 'hamsters': -2}
>>> import collections
>>> sum(scores.get(word.lower(), 0) * freq for word, freq in collections.Counter(s.split()).items())
3
```

and split up:

```
>>> sum = 0
>>> counts = collections.Counter(s.split())
>>> for word, freq in counts.items():
...     sum += scores.get(word.lower(), 0) * freq
...
>>> sum
3
```

Notable features:

- The score isn't 8 (as you claimed above) but 3, because the word `dogs` only appears once in the string you gave. If you want to count the word `dog` twice, you will need a (much) more complicated algorithm, probably interfacing with a pluralisation library to handle cases like `child -> children` and `man -> men`. This will not be easy or necessarily correct.
- I've included `.lower()` to ignore capitalisation in the string you gave. If you don't want that, just remove the call.
- You misspelt "hamster" :p.

Comment: Be advised, doesn't work in Python 2 (collections.Counter not implemented in 2.x)

Comment: @Steve: Works in 2.7, the current version, although it is new in 2.7.

Comment: @katrielalex:  Ah, I see.  I didn't realize which part of  http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html the "New in version 3.1" was referring to

Comment: @Steve V: remove `dev/` from your URL and you'll get the Python 2.x documentation. The page you linked shows that it's new in Python 3.1 *for the 3.x series*.

Comment: Learn something new every day on this site.  Thanks @Greg!

Comment: "..you will need a (much) more complicated algorithm.." - that's not entirely true. If you use e.g. `string.count` and look for the word 'dog', it appears twice. That's not much more complicated.

Comment: @sje397: which is great when dog is in dogs, but not so great when it's in dogfish.

Comment: @sje: Or when `man` has a score and `men` appears in the string.

Comment: @Hugh, @katrielalex: normally these kinds of scoring systems are designed for that sort of issue, e.g. Bayesian net or somesuch - you don't care if it's 'viagra' or 'cheapviagra'

Comment: @kat: That edit is *really* nice.  I wish i'd thought of that.  +1

Comment: Great comments and I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Use katrielalex's answer if possible, it's cleaner than mine.  If you don't have Python 2.7 (like me), this may work for you:

```
sentence = "Dogs are great pets and hamsters are bad pets. That is why I want a dog"

scores = {'dog' : 5, 'hamster' : -2} 

occurrences = {}

for key in scores: 
  m = re.findall(key, sentence , re.IGNORECASE)
  occurrences[key] = len(m)

totalScore = 0

for word in occurrences:
  totalScore += scores.get(word.lower(), 0) * occurrences[word]

print totalScore
```

I did "dogs" -> "dog" in your scores dictionary, on the assumption that it was a typo.  If you change it back, your result will be 3 without pluralization.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

mtext ="Dogs are great pets and hamsters are bad pets. That is why I want a dog"
for key in Dict: 
    p = re.compile('dog', re.IGNORECASE)
    NuOfDogs=len(p.findall(mtext)) #returns number of occurences

Answer (score 0):

Another variation of katrielalex's answer for people stuck with Python 2.6,

put this snippet in a file (counter.py for instance): http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611/

then you can use the following code:

```
from counter import Counter

counts = Counter(text.split())
for word, freq in counts.items():
    sum += scores.get(word.lower(), 0) * freq 
...
```

Pretty much the same except it works with older Python's versions.